# How to calculate the timer while items at added runtime in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

we have test the automation teascase.so i have added tabcotrol and using the button click event to add the 40 tabitem at Runtime.In our requirement how to calculate the timer at while adding the tabitem.

Comment: Do you want to calculate how long time it took to add 40 tab items?

Comment: yes..i want calculate the millsecond at that time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve it is to compare the time before and after.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now; // When you start.
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    // Your logic for adding the tab here...
    AddTab();
}
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - now; //When you're done.
Console.WriteLine(elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

`elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` will be the total number of milliseconds it took to complete the action. Give or take a few milliseconds for handling the time compare.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It works for me.But when load add the tabitem means first time it calculates the 35 millsecond and the next we run to load tabitem means it shows 40sec..loaded time was different at each time.

Comment: @ASHOKKUMARM Although this answer is OK for simple operations. `TimeSpan` of complex operations are likely to be affected by other applications that run on the same PC/Server as well. For an actual measurement, I'd recommend using either `PerformanceCounters` or `TotalProcessorTime`

Comment: Yes, I personally think that the answer provided by @Noctis will provide a better result. The answer given above will work under simple conditions, but will not be very exact.

Answer (score 0):

Though Smoksnes answer is good, if you are looking for more precision, it is advisable to use the `StopWatch`.

Here's the MSDN documentation: [stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Main benefit is it has a higher precision (as noted above).
An example would be:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```